# Positioning elements in equal height columns

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the jsFinddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/florian53/Wpwft/7/

Within these 3 columns, 24 px vertical padding needs to be included above all 3 icons so that the text does not run close to the top of the icons. Do you have any ideas how to make this possible, keeping the height of the columns equal?

Answer (score 0):

see this

http://jsfiddle.net/Wpwft/8/

```
.span3 {
    width: 156px;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

just use **`display:table-cell`**  in span3 class

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) simple and neat only css solution of your problem. All you need to do then is to position your icons at the bottom of the containers.

edit:

I just found a problem in the tutorial I mentioned above. If i don't remove the `overflow:hidden` rule from the `container3` text doesn't show up. I'm still working on it.